pandas read_csv silently not parsing separate date & time fields despite provision of date_format
I'm am reading a CSV file AirQualityUCI.csv containing date data [1].  Here are a sample of 10 lines, including the 1st line for field names:
Date;Time;CO(GT);PT08.S1(CO);NMHC(GT);C6H6(GT);PT08.S2(NMHC);NOx(GT);PT08.S3(NOx);NO2(GT);PT08.S4(NO2);PT08.S5(O3);T;RH;AH;;
10/03/2004;18.00.00;2,6;1360;150;11,9;1046;166;1056;113;1692;1268;13,6;48,9;0,7578;;
10/03/2004;19.00.00;2;1292;112;9,4;955;103;1174;92;1559;972;13,3;47,7;0,7255;;
10/03/2004;20.00.00;2,2;1402;88;9,0;939;131;1140;114;1555;1074;11,9;54,0;0,7502;;
10/03/2004;21.00.00;2,2;1376;80;9,2;948;172;1092;122;1584;1203;11,0;60,0;0,7867;;
31/03/2005;06.00.00;0,9;1068;-200;6,1;816;191;681;80;1264;1011;12,6;71,5;1,0380;;
31/03/2005;07.00.00;4,0;1531;-200;23,6;1394;673;407;133;1860;1683;12,7;69,6;1,0206;;
31/03/2005;08.00.00;4,1;1184;-200;10,9;1012;547;567;170;1397;1341;16,8;51,6;0,9818;;
31/03/2005;09.00.00;1,9;1064;-200;6,8;848;275;692;139;1212;1014;20,3;40,1;0,9439;;
31/03/2005;10.00.00;1,3;996;-200;4,9;759;200;773;124;1119;751;21,0;37,3;0,9139;;

The ingestion code is adapted from here, which does not have the date_format specification below:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(
    "AirQualityUCI.csv", sep=';', decimal=',',
    date_format='%d/%m/%Y',
    parse_dates=[["Date", "Time"]],
    na_values=[-200],
    usecols=["Date", "Time", "CO(GT)", "T", "RH", "AH"]
).rename(
    columns={
        "CO(GT)": "co",
        "Date_Time": "tstamp",
        "T": "temp_c",
        "RH": "rel_hum",
        "AH": "abs_hum",
    }
).set_index("tstamp")

The use of the date_format option eliminated a previous warning:
c:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\Some.Path\trygroupby.py:28:
UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be
parsed individually, falling back to `dateutil`. To ensure parsing
is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format.
  df = pd.read_csv(

Despite this, date/time index is still merely a string, as it was before the use of date_format:
>>> df.index.day_name()
      AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'day_name'
>>> type(df.index.min())
      str

What am I doing wrong with date_format?
Notes
[1] Here is the host webpage.  The last few lines of AirQualityUCI.csv contain nothing but empty fields, which I removed.

I think the problem is that the Time column isn't in %m/%d/%Y format specified by date_format.

Maybe use day_first=True?

@Barmar: Sorry, I didn't include enough records from the input file.  I've added 5 more lines showing that the date format is correct (day/month/year).  I also tried dayfirst=True, but the results remain the same.

The problem is the Time column, not Date.

@Barmer That's it!  Would you be willing to post your comment as the answer?  I used date_format='%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S' and did not set dayfirst.

I want to post an answer, but I'm not sure I understand the question. Why were you expecting that date_format to work when it didn't specify the time format?

Also, please minimize the data and code; you should be able to get it down to the two date/time columns plus one other. And I think just two rows would suffice, one of each date. For reference see [mre] and How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

You can post your own answer.

Here's a gist with an MRE if you want to use it

I forgot to mention, as part of clarifying the question, please write a better title. See [ask] for tips.

I changed it to "pandas read_csv silently not parsing separate date & time fields despite provision of date_format".  Frankly, I didn't know it was a related to date_format because the cited source of the code had no date_format.  After adding a date_format option, I wasn't sure if the remaining problem was related to date_format because the warning was gone.

The issue was with the Time field of the input data.  It was resolved by adding time-formatting to read_csv's date_format option: date_format='%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S'.
Thanks to @Barmar for pointing this out in the comments.
